# MAC addresses of hosts that violate port-security

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, cisco-catalyst, port-security

Do hosts that violate port-security show up in the mac-address table, or is this only in the logs? What would the log entry look like that has the violating address? We're on Cisco 2960X.

Comment: I'm using "protect" mode, but I'm assuming that it's the same for all options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Logs are generated such as:

```
%PM-4-ERR_DISABLE and %PORT_SECURITY-2-PSECURE_VIOLATION
```

The port status is also changed from Secure-Up to Secure-Down.

Updated:

Port security learns unauthorized MAC addresses with a bit set that causes traffic to them or from them to be dropped. The show mac-address-table command displays the unauthorized MAC addresses, but does not display the state of the bit. (CSCeb76844)

Comment: So I could just show mac address-table on the ports with port security and still see any extra addresses, right?